# ASP.NET MVC Wild Card Controller any parameter routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to have Controller/Action so that when I navigate to:

```
mysite.com/whatever. i type here will pipe into...a ! string.

public ActionResult Index(string anything)
{
    // anything = whatever. i type here will pipe into...a ! string.
    return View();
}
```

Do I need to setup a custom route?

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to handle periods, etc.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*anything}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Comment: That's because a period causes IIS to take over and try to statically serve what it thinks is a file instead of handing it off to MVC.

Comment: I have never tried this but attribute routing might be something you can look into. Not sure if it will take the period like Chris said.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts i still haven't figured out an ideal solution here. is there anything out of the box?

Answer (score 5):

If you constrain your route with a catch-all regex:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{*anything}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    new { anything = @"^(.*)?$" }
);
```

And ensure you have the UrlRoutingModule [set up in your web.config with no precondition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7148231/1043198) to ensure that even unmanaged requests (e.g. those deemed to have extensions) are put through the routing module, your catchall route should work fine.